# Is there any GCP Dataflow template for "Pub/Sub to Cloud Spanner"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I am trying to find out if there is any GCP Dataflow template available for data ingestion with "Pub/Sub to Cloud Spanner". I have found there is already a default GCP dataflow template available with example - "Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery".
So, I am interested to see if I can do data ingestion to spanner in stream or batch mode and how the behavior would be

Answer (score 1):

There is a Dataflow template to import Avro files in batch mode that you can use by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import). Unfortunately a Cloud Pub/Sub streaming template is not available yet. If you would like, you can [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190851&template=0).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried to do something like use "projects/pubsub-public-data/topics/taxirides-realtime" and "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_Avro" template to load sample data file to my gcp storage. Then I stopped this stream job and created another batch job with "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Avro_to_Cloud_Spanner" template. But the batch job failed with below error,

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec: gs://cardataavi/archive/spanner-export.json
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.maybeAdjustEmptyMatchResult(FileSystems.java:166)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:153)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO$MatchAll$MatchFn.process(FileIO.java:636)`

It seems, right now spanner support only Avro data format which has Spanner specific format. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: Spanner import should work with Avro files from any source. So your staged files in GCS should be importable. However you have to manually create the spanner-export.json file with the [required metadata](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-non-spanner#create-export-json). Please follow all the instructions in the page, including creating the Spanner schema before the import.

Comment: Thanks Biswa, I have checked the documentation. It seems I need to first create a schema file from the Spanner table (to be my data sink) and use that while loading data into it from Avro.